# Rating slider not firing when using jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I trying to get a slider to work in a jquery ui site.  It works fine when the page it loaded, but when starting at the homepage and browsing to that page, the slider doesn't run.  All the JS code is in a .js file that is loaded on every page; including homepage.  I know the jquery ui makes an ajax experience so it doesn't load the full page, so keeping the required code in the .js should allow it to run; i think.  I've been looking at this for a while and i'm missing something pretty basic understand on this i'm guessing.

How the slider looks when working:

[image: Current Slider]

Code:

```
<div class="spacer-b20 TextSliderBox">
   <label class="field">
       <input type="text" id="slider1value" name="slider1value" class="gui-input" value="1">
       <input type="text" name="EventID" class="TextSliderBox" value="">
       <div id="slider1"></div>
     </label> 
</div>
```

In the site .js file:

```
$(function() {
  $("#slider1").slider({
    value:1,
    min: 1,
    max: 5,
    step: 1,
    range: "max",
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#slider1value").val(ui.value);
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: Just for clarification - did you create two pages (homepage and page2, we'll say), and when loading page2 by URL the slider works, but when loading the homepage, and clicking a button which then loads page2 via AJAX, the slider doesn't work?

Comment: @mark.hch That is correct.

Comment: Okay. Then my assumption is that you are including jQuery and jQuery UI on both the homepage and page2 as well, so the library loads twice. In the AJAX call that loads page2, you can use a selector after the URL to just load the `.TextSliderBox` element (this way it only loads that element and strips out any additional `<script>` tags). For example `$('#view').load('page2.php .TextSliderBox');`. BTW I just learned this was possible 23 hours ago.

Comment: I think you're right in it's loading twice.  I hadn't thought about filtering the second page.  You may have learned it 23 hrs ago but it's still new to me so it's time to go searching.  Worst case, i'll disable ajax and just load pages normally.  It will be a bit slower but will at least work.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a ready function:

```
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: He's already got that. `$(function() {...});` is different syntax for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up moving some functions to the .js file and going with a different slider which is css based.  Works great now.